# High level project workflow

Tags: process, management

We are a small software company trying our hand at our second game. Since our first games' process was a living nightmare (since we used webdevelopment workflow) I have decided to educate myself on how to manage a game project on a high level.

How does your process work, from idea to launch? Preferably in situations where you have a team that needs to cooperate.

I've seen these 2 links, which are useful in a way, but was wondering if there are better/more comprehensive ways to do this?

http://www.goodcontroller.com/blog/?p=136

http://gogogic.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/symbol6-how-we-created-an-iphone-game/

All input would be infinitely appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to gamedev stackexchange!

Comment: Are you familiar with common software development models like scrum, the v-model or the spiral model? Personally, I consider scrum to be pretty suitable for game development because it leaves room for new ideas during the development, but YMMV.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly made your game process "a living nightmare" and which aspects of the webdevelopment workflow turned out to be unsuitable for your project and why?

Comment: related question: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116/what-are-the-most-popular-software-development-methodologies-used-by-game-studio

Comment: Howdy, thanks for the replies! We are familiar with SCRUM (which does work brilliantly for the actual development). However, before the coding starts we'd like some tips on getting set on concept and mechanics. The last time the problem was changing specs and mechanics during developmen.

Comment: SCRUM is supposed to be *good* when specs change during development... Why did it work so badly?

Comment: Well, because the concept slowly fell apart. Feature creep I guess.

Comment: That means this is not a problem of high level project workflow, but sadly the game idea itself...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at **Beyond Scrum: Lean and Kanban for Game Developers** http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3847/beyond_scrum_lean_and_kanban_for_.php?print=1